# Tensorflow variational autoencoder, how is decoder connected?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, autoencoder

In the keras example at https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html, the section "Variational autoencoder (VAE)" writes

```
z = layers.Lambda(sampling)([z_mean, z_log_sigma])
# Create encoder
encoder = keras.Model(inputs, [z_mean, z_log_sigma, z], name='encoder')

# Create decoder
latent_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(latent_dim,), name='z_sampling')
x = layers.Dense(intermediate_dim, activation='relu')(latent_inputs)
outputs = layers.Dense(original_dim, activation='sigmoid')(x)
decoder = keras.Model(latent_inputs, outputs, name='decoder')
```

I am confused which layer is connected to `latent_inputs` and where does it define the connection? For example, in `vae.fit()`, `x_train` is passed as VAE input and goes to the layer `inputs`, which is defined as `inputs = keras.Input(shape=(original_dim,))` and input of the VAE model is defined as `vae = keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_mlp')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing one important part of the tutorial:

```
# instantiate VAE model
outputs = decoder(encoder(inputs)[2])
vae = keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name='vae_mlp')
```

In Keras, a `Model` can be used as a `Layer` in an other `Model`. ([Source](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional_api#all_models_are_callable_just_like_layers))

So the output `z` of the encoder is fed as the input of the decoder to form the VAE model.